# Echo uploaded file value in the form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

I have got a simple form which has few fields like name, address, etc and two fields for uploading images and finally two buttons, one for preview and the other is a final submission.

I want to make the form much more user friendly, so that when the user clicks the preview button, I show a small prview and still if the user has to makes some changes in the fields which he has already entered, I want to the show the form echoing all the values which the user has entered.

In case of text field I am just using this piece of PHP code inside the  tag to echo the name

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : ""); ?>" />
```

and so for other fields in the form.

My question is that how can I echo/show the uploaded file names even after clicking the preview button, which in my case does upload the two images into the specified directory, that is I can see that the uploaded images are stored in the specified directory. In case if the user wants to upload only one image, then he can see the names of the already uploaded images in the output form, so that the user doesnot need to choose both the fields for uploading the images one more time.

I hope I explained it in a understandable way, in case if something is unclear then please let me know.

P.S. A small example would be good to follow.

Regards
Maks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you're using the `file` input type you cannot modify their values in any way.  This is done for the safety of the user so that you don't specify a default file to upload from the user's system (you could theoretically upload a sensitive file if they didn't change the field from the default).

You could try using a `text` input field that's read-only and shows the url to the file the user uploaded.  An edit button next to this field could create a file upload field and allow them to upload a new file.